# Mapping to Shared Drive on Linksys Router

Tags: networking, mount, file-sharing, file-server

I have a 2 TB Seagate drive on my Linksys WRT1900AC router USB. I can access it as a network drive on my Windows 10 PC and as an ftp site when I'm remote. I'm trying to access it on my RPi 3B+ but I keep having problems connecting.

I created `/home/pi/SEAGATE/share`

then

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=John,password=mypassword //192.168.1.1/S_Drive SEAGATE/share
```

but I get a `112 Host is down` error and the share directory is empty.

I tried

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and added

```
//192.168.1.1/S_Drive /home/pi/SEAGATE/share cifs username=John,password=mypassword 0 0
```

but after reboot I still don't have the drive and the `SEAGATE/share` folder is empty.

I can access the file using FTP both using LAN and WAN IP addresses.
The Linksys has not been flashed to OpenWrt, and is running original OS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

- I was missing leading `/`
- `vers=1.0` may have helped
- Drive had two logical names.  S-Drive wasn't working. Seagate was.

Use:

```
sudo mount --verbose -o username=John,password=********,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1/Seagate /home/pi/SEAGATE/share/
```